# Меню и кросбраузерность

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть меню с разными по ширине блоками. 
В хроме меню занимает 100% объема, а в мозиле переходит на другую строку. То есть меню уже в 2 строки!

Размер блоков регулирует padding от текста меню. Паддинг пиксельный.

Как правильно сверстать это меню, или написать исключение для моззилы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это css хаки надо применить. Пиши их в конце ну или после того кода, который работает для всех остальных браузеров.
Вот то, что нашел, если не подойдет погугли. Тк там для разных версий мозилы есть.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() 
{
бла бла бла 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой недавно. Она заключается в том что Mozilla немного по другому отображает шрифты. На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/8548/) обсуждалась подобная проблема.
Лично я через js определил браузер и для последнего элемента padding поставил на пару пикселей меньше

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему задав ширину для каждого блока в пикселях